# module.exports a function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, module, export

I want to export function and variable from one file ( module ) to another . This is how it is

```
    // animals.js 
        function weight () {
         return "90kgs"; 
    }
    module.exports = weight();

    // tiger.js 
    var animal = require('./animals.js');
    module.exports = { 
             'animalWeight' : function animal.weight(),
             'stripes' : true 
    }


   // zoo.js
   var tiger = require('./tiger.js');
   tiger.animalWeight(); // should return 90kgs
   tiger.stripes ; // should return true
```

How to achieve above. I get following error

```
   'animalWeight' : function animal.weight(),
                                   ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Answer (score 1):

When you export a function, you'd reference it

```
function weight () {
     return "90kgs"; 
}
module.exports = weight;
```

now when you import it, you get that function, and can reference it again

```
var animal = require('./animals.js');

module.exports = { 
    'animalWeight' : animal,
    'stripes' : true 
}
```

and when you import that again, you can call that function

```
var tiger = require('./tiger.js');

tiger.animalWeight(); // "90kgs"
tiger.stripes ; // true
```